# How to massively change the column reference in an excel sheet's formulas?

Tags: excel

How to massively change the column reference in an excel sheet's formulas?

For example there is this column that has formulas that include REFERENCES of column G (G2, G23, G30, etc) and I want that massively change to column H (H2, H23, H33, etc).

Did not find any existing relevant q&a, maybe did not search enough, sorry and thanks in advance!

Comment: Which column contains the formulas ??

Answer (score 1):

Click on column **A** and perform:

**Insert > Column**

Column **G** will become column **H** and any formulas in the worksheet that referred to cells in column **G** will now refer to cells in column **H**:

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, it's ok I 've found it and it's simple. I just switched to formula view (Formulas menu), selected the column that give me the results and replaced (Ctrl+H) the g with h. And it's all done. Have a good evening.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly put this together, the replacement function leaves a lot to be desired! (very lazy, you'd need to improve it probably)

`R` should be set to the column with the formula you want to change the reference in.

Just a proof of concept really. Make sure you save a copy of your workbook if you test it.

```
Sub Main()
Dim R As Range: Set R = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$E$1:$E$2")
Dim Cell As Range
Dim CellPrecedent As Range
Dim CellPrecedents As Range
Dim Retry As Boolean: Retry = False
For Each Cell In R.Cells
    On Error Resume Next
    Set CellPrecedents = Cell.Precedents
    On Error GoTo 0

    If CellPrecedents Is Nothing Then
        ' skip
    Else
        For Each CellPrecedent In CellPrecedents
            If CellPrecedent.Column = 7 Then ' 7 == G
                Cell.Formula = Replace(Cell.Formula, "G", "H")
                GoTo Breakout
            End If
        Next CellPrecedent
    End If
Breakout:
Next Cell
If Retry Then Main
End Sub
```

Comment: If column **E** contains a formula like *=GCD(G1,2)* your macro will make it *=HCD(H1,2)* .............It changes ALL "G" into "H" ..........even characters in worksheet functions.  You may want to modify this to change only "G" followed by a numeral.

Comment: Indeed, that is why I said the replacement function was very lazy. Your answer is much simpler.

Comment: **I like your approach.**  If you are willing to update it a little bit, I will up-vote.